# Can't access to vpn after connect via command line using ovpn file

Tags: dns, ubuntu-server, openvpn

I need to connect a machine with Ubuntu Server 18.04 to a VPN using command line using the ovpn file, the ovpn file is like this:

```
#OpenVPN Server conf
pull-filter ignore "redirect-gateway"
route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0
auth-user-pass login.conf
tls-client
client
dev tun
proto udp
tun-mtu 1400
remote 256.34.90.X 1195
pkcs12 Johan.p12
cipher BF-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 3
ns-cert-type server
```

The command I execute is: **sudo openvpn Johan.ovpn**

The output after use the command is:

```
...
Mon Jan 13 11:50:06 2020 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

After this, I can connect to Internet, but I cannot access to vpn resources. It seems like it can not resolve against the vpn domains.

When I use a curl against vpn domains it can not resolve.

What must I do or include in the ovpn to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

What I did to make it work is this:

1- In a terminal connect to the VPN like this:

```
sudo openvpn Johan.ovpn
```

2- Use the command systemd-resolve to define the dns server and the domain

```
sudo systemd-resolve --set-dns=192.168.1.X --set-dns=192.168.1.X --set-domain=company-domain.com --interface=tun0
```

Where 192.168.1.X is the dns server
After this all works.

Comment: What is `192.168.1.183`?  The OpenVPN IP of the Ubuntu Server?  And `234.56.78.90` is it's public IP?

Comment: It's the dns server's ip and 234.56.78.90 is the public IP of the server